# Raspberry Pi 1B Secure Configuration Register

Tags: exception, qemu, bare-metal, armv6

Now I make low level bare-metal tool for RPi.
And I need to get **Secure Configuration Register** value.
I wrote the following instruction **`mrc p15, 0, r0, c1, c1, 0`** to get it.
But CPU goes into **Undefined Exception Mode** and **CPSR** value is **0x600001DB**.

Instruction of reading SCR value  is the first instruction being executed by CPU.

I'd read **ARM1176JZF-S TRM r0p7** several times but I've not found any restriction on using SCR reading instruction except being CPU in the **Secure Privileged Mode** but according to TRM this CPU starts from **Secure Privileged Mode**. If to be more concrete the initial mode is **Secure Supervisor Mode**.

I use the following command to execute code with QEMU 
qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -M versatilepb -m 256 -nographic -kernel start.elf -s -S -monitor stdio

I can't understand what I overlooked?

Comment: you sure that qemu accurately represents the logic.  What happens when you run on hardware?

Comment: No, I'm not sure, but I hope. As for hardware, I've not run it yet.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU's versatilepb board does not support TrustZone: it creates a CPU with that feature disabled.

Other QEMU board models do support TZ, if you want to play with it: for instance vexpress-a9, vexpress-a15 and raspi2; also "virt", if you pass -machine secure=on on the QEMU command line.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll try.